# Can't convert STRING to INT in C++ in LINUX

Tags: linux, string, int, atoi

I've tried many ways, as detailed in here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13135/

Most of them work if I run the file on Windows, but when I try to do so on LINUX, none of them works.
For example, I try to do:

```
  string str = "123";
  int sp;
  istringstream ( str ) >> sp;
```

But it gives me the error: "invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::istringstream’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:67: error: declaration of ‘struct std::istringstream’"

Other option was 'atoi', but it says that 'atoi was not defined in this scope.'

Any ideas why its happening?

Comment: For "atoi" `#include <cstdlib>`.  For "istringstream", `#include <istream>`.  You should also add `using namespace std;`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest usage of *atoi*, it is not ANSI compliant. C++ 11 has *to_string* method (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). In older c++, you can try something like *fprintf*.

Comment: @user1818446 wants to convert from string to int. not the other way ;)

Answer (score 5):

as for the atoi() function, you need to include the cstdlib (`#include <cstdlib>`) header.

then you can use it like this:

```
string str= "123"; 
int sp = atoi(str.c_str());
```

it will tell the string object to act as a const char* pointing to a C-style string (most probably best known as a string with the zero terminator \0).

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX way to covert `std::string` to `int` will be `atoi()`

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
string str = "123";
int sp = atoi( str.c_str() );
```

If you want to convert not only to `int` but to many types, it is better to use `stringstream`. However, beware the increased compilation time.

Comment: Yes, it worked -  I guess I forgot to add '#include <cstdlib>'

Comment: `istringstream ( str ) >> sp;` can also work - please see my comments above.  Glad you got it resolved :)!

Comment: @paulsm4: the pitfall of istringstring is compilation time.